# MFT with EVR gives out less number of frames

Tags: video, render, ms-media-foundation

I have a topology as below, it works fine for all frames of video sequence:

Source->Video Decoder MFT->Custom Video Edit MFT->Video Encoder MFT->Custom Sink MFT

But If I insert a Tee node after "Custom Video Edit MFT" to connect to Enhanced Video Renderer (EVR) as well, then the application doesn't run for all frames of the video sequence.

I tried to figure out the cause using mftrace, but it didn't help much. Is there a possibility of frame skips by any node if custom MFT takes too long time? I appreciate if some hints to debug this issue or any wild guess.

FYI, this issue observed only when I try with UHD (3840x2160) resolution video. It works well for HD (1920x1080) resolution.

Comment: Did you setup output node to MF_TOPONODE_DISCARDABLE ?

Comment: @mofo77 Yes,I tried by setting one of the output nodes to MF_TOPONODE_DISCARDABLE.

Comment: Setup MF_TOPONODE_DISCARDABLE means that frames will be dropped. You  say you don't want. Is your MFT encoder uses GPU encoding ? You can face GPU bandwidth limitation.

Comment: @mofo77 Yes, my MFT encoder uses GPU encoding. I have posted this issue even in MSDN forum [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/789b6e0c-9b34-4d58-bceb-484fc0da21b4/tee-node-and-custom-mft?forum=mediafoundationdevelopment) with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally the issue is resolved by turning off the MF_SESSION_QUALITY_MANAGER as below, it avoids possible frame dropping:

```
   CComPtr<IMFAttributes> attrib;
    MFCreateAttributes(&attrib, 1);
    attrib->SetGUID(MF_SESSION_QUALITY_MANAGER, GUID_NULL);
    hr = MFCreateMediaSession(attrib, &_mediaSession);
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to setup MF_TOPONODE_PRIMARYOUTPUT on the tee node.

Your output encoder should be the primary output, and the renderer output, the second.

Also, use MF_TOPONODE_RATELESS for your sink, because by default, it is not.

Don't use MF_TOPONODE_DISCARDABLE, because you don't want to.

If your problem persists, i can create a tee node transform to check what happens. But for now, it's not sure that the tee node is the problem. Perhaps it is the media session...

Comment: I tried with your suggestion, but issue still persists. One other question, how can I get the statistics of EVR? I tried by using IQualProp interface of "IMFVideoDisplayControl", but it is not working.

Comment: "The application doesn't run for all frames of the video sequence" : do it concerns the evr sink, the custom sink, or both ? instead of IMFVideoDisplayControl and IQualProp, you should try with IMFQualityAdvise and SetDropMode.

Comment: "The application doesn't run for all frames of the video sequence", this statement is based on observations made in "Custom Video Edit MFT" and "Custom Sink" (I used frame counters in those two TopoNodes). In order to understand the issue presence in EVR, I tried collecting the stats of EVR. But, I failed to collect EVR stats. I guess both EVR and Custom sinks have the same issue of not running entire sequence.